# asymptotic density of odd numbers which are products of two primes

Tags: number-theory

Consider the set $A:=\{x\,|x=p\cdot q\}$where $p$ and $q$ are odd primes. What is the asymptotic density of $A$?

Second question: is there a $k$ such that the set consisting of all positive integers with no more than $k$ prime factors (multiplicities are counted) has nonzero asymptotic density?

Answer (score 2):

The asymptotic density is 0. If $A(x)$ denotes the number of odd semiprimes less than or equal to $x$, $A(x)\sim\frac{x\log\log x}{\log x}$.

To the second question, there is no such k, whether you count multiplicity or not. The set of numbers with at most a million prime factors has asymptotic density 0.

Comment: thanks Charles; I appreciate your prompt reply. Can you please suggest a good reference?

Comment: The standard reference is Landau, _Handbuch der Lehre von der Verteilung der Primzahlen_. If you don't speak German, Hardy & Wright is a good standard reference.  Tenenbaum's _Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory_ should have it as well.